# A "fast" way for  computing $ \prod \limits_{i=1}^{45}(1+\tan i^\circ) $?

Tags: trigonometry, products

> Which  is the fastest **paper-pencil approach** to compute the product $$ \prod
>  \limits_{i=1}^{45}(1+\tan i^\circ) $$

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Using
$$
1+\tan x = \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\cos x} = \frac{\sqrt{2} \cos (45^{\circ} - x)}{\cos x}, 
$$
the product can be written as:
$$
\prod_{x=1}^{45}(1+\tan x^\circ) = 2^{45/2} \prod_{x=1}^{45} \frac{\cos (45 - x)^{\circ}}{\cos x^{\circ}} \stackrel{(1)}{=}  2^{45/2}  \cdot \frac{\prod\limits_{x=0}^{44} \cos x^{\circ}}{\prod\limits_{x=1}^{45} \cos x^{\circ}} \stackrel{(2)}{=} 2^{45/2} \cdot \frac{\cos 0}{\cos 45^{\circ}} = 2^{23},
$$
where we

1. reindexed the product in the numerator, and
2. cancelled the common factors.

---

**Another approach.** If $x+y = 45^{\circ}$, then
$$
1 = \tan(x+y) = \frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1 - \tan x \tan y},
$$
which rearranges to
$$
\tan x \tan y + \tan x + \tan y = 1 \quad \implies \quad (1+\tan x)(1+\tan y) = 2.
$$
Now plug in $x = 0^{\circ}, 1^{\circ}, 2^{\circ}, \ldots, 45^{\circ}$, so that $y$ takes the same values but in the opposite order. Multiplying all these equations, we get
$$
\left[ \prod_{x=0}^{45} (1+\tan x^\circ) \right]^2 = 2^{46}.
$$
Taking square-roots and noting that $1+\tan 0^\circ = 1$, we get the answer.

Comment: I like the second answer even better.  I wish I could vote up again!

Comment: @DJC:Second answer is nice,but I guess not much of intuitive under exam constraints if you haven't did something very similar to this before.

Comment: Amazing idea - Very neat!

Answer (score 4):

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188746/calculating-sqrt3-tan-1-circ-sqrt3-tan2-circ-sqrt/188749#188749), $$(\cot A + \tan y)(\cot A+ \tan(A-y))=\csc^2A \text{ if } A\ne m\pi\text{ where }m\text{ is any integer}$$

Putting $A=45^\circ, (1 + \tan y)(1+ \tan(45^\circ-y))=\csc^245^\circ=2$

Now, putting $y=1^\circ,2^\circ,3^\circ,\cdots,\lfloor\frac{45}2\rfloor^\circ=22^\circ$ and multiplying them we get, $$\prod_{1\le r\le 22}(1+\tan r^\circ)(1+\tan(45-r)^\circ)=2^{22}$$

$$\implies   \prod_{1\le r\le 44}(1+\tan r^\circ)=2^{22}$$

The unpaired $1+\tan45^\circ=1+1=2$

Answer (score 0):

Just tell a computer to calculate them.  For example in R this runs almost instantly

```
> prod(1+tan((1:45)*pi/180))
[1] 8388608
```

Comment: This is actually quantitative aptitude question,which requires pencil-paper approach only.

Comment: Perhaps you should have put that in the question at the start

Comment: @Henry: It was kind of obvious.

Comment: No matter what others say, this is the fast way