# Value of a series in $\tan$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

> **Question:** The value of: $$(1+\tan 1^o)(1+\tan 2^o)(1+\tan 3^o)...(1+\tan 44^o)$$ is:
>
> A) 2
>
> B) A multiple of 22
>
> C) A multiple of 4
>
> D) Not an integer

I'm not sure how I would solve this question. However, by intuition, I would say that the number wouldn't be an integer. As all the terms in the bracket are between 1 and 2, their product shouldn't give an integral value. Am I right?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304461/x-1-tan-1-circ1-tan-2-circ1-tan-3-circ-ldots1-tan?rq=1

Comment: $\frac 32$ and $\frac 43$ are between $1$ and $2$ too -- do you contend their product is not an integer?

Comment: Hint: $(1 + \tan(a^\circ))(1+\tan((45-a)^\circ) = 2$

Comment: @HenningMakholm Aha.... Don't know how I missed that. Thanks anyways I have checked the similar questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Note I found something interesting $(1+tan(1degree))(1+tan(44degree))\approx 2$ this can easily be proved by simplifying $(1+tan(a))(1+tan(45-a))$