# If $y = (1 + \tan A)(1 - \tan B)$, where $A - B = \frac{\pi}{4}$ , then find the value of $(y+1)^{y+1}$.

Tags: trigonometry

> If  $y = (1 + \tan A)(1 - \tan B)$, where $A - B = \frac{\pi}{4}$ ,
>   then find the value of $(y+1)^{y+1}$.

I have tried this question and I think that it is something along the lines of $\tan (A-B) = \frac{\tan A - tan B}{1 + \tan A \tan B} \Rightarrow   1- \tan A \tan B = \tan A \tan B$.

Also if you solved this question, can you rate the difficulty level of this question (I just want to understand where I stand)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446402/if-alpha-beta-dfrac-pi4-prove-that-1-tan-alpha1-tan-beta and   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188746/calculating-sqrt3-tan-1-circ-sqrt3-tan2-circ-sqrt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 
$$
1=\tan (\pi/4)=\tan (A-B)=\frac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A \tan B}
$$
which implies
$$
\tan A-\tan B=1+\tan A\tan B
$$
Your quantity is then
$$
y=(1+\tan A)(1-\tan B)=1+\tan A-\tan B-\tan A\tan B=2
$$
hence $(y+1)^{y+1}=3^3=27$.

Comment: If y = 2 shouldn't y+1=3 and $(y+1)^{y+1}$ = $3^{3}$ = 27