# How to calculate $\left( 1+\tan 5^\circ\right) \left( 1+\tan 10^\circ\right)\left( 1+\tan 15^\circ\right)\cdots\left( 1+\tan 40^\circ\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

I curious practical solution.(Step by step)

$\left( 1+\tan 5^\circ\right) \left( 1+\tan 10^\circ\right)\left( 1+\tan 15^\circ\right)\cdots\left( 1+\tan 40^\circ\right)$

Answer is $16$.

Comment: Do you mean degree instead of radian?

Comment: @frank000 sorry.degree

Comment: Did you come up with any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "this sum" ??

Comment: Isn't it a product?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188746/calculating-sqrt3-tan-1-circ-sqrt3-tan2-circ-sqrt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, observe that
$$1=\tan 45^\circ =\tan(5^\circ+40^\circ)=\frac{\tan5^\circ+\tan40^\circ}{1-\tan5^\circ\tan40^\circ}.$$
Then we have $\tan5^\circ+\tan40^\circ=1-\tan5^\circ\tan40^\circ$, and thus
\begin{align}
(1+\tan5^\circ)(1+\tan40^\circ)&=1+\tan5^\circ\tan40^\circ+\tan5^\circ+\tan40^\circ\\
&=1+\tan5^\circ\tan40^\circ+1-\tan5^\circ\tan40^\circ\\
&=2.
\end{align}
Hence we conclude that
$$(1+\tan5^\circ)(1+\tan10^\circ)\cdots(1+\tan40^\circ)=2^4=16.$$

Answer (score 11):

If $\displaystyle A+B = \frac{\pi}{4}\;,$ Then $(1+\tan A)(1+\tan B) = 2$

So $(1+\tan 5^0)(1+\tan 40^0)=2$ and $(1+\tan 10^0)(1+\tan 35^0)=2$

and $(1+\tan 15^0)(1+\tan 30^0)=2$ and $(1+\tan 20^0)(1+\tan 35^0)=2$

So $$(1+\tan 5^0)(1+\tan 40^0)(1+\tan 10^0)(1+\tan 35^0)(1+\tan 15^0)(1+\tan 30^0)(1+\tan 20^0)(1+\tan 35^0)=2^4=16$$

Comment: Very nice observation!