# Complexity of products/quotients of sums of roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, computational-complexity

This question was inspired by another recent question  [(here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294052/how-does-one-calculate-the-product-of-tan-1-circ-tan-45-circ) .

That older question asked somehow vaguely if the expression $\prod_{k=1}^m \tan(\frac{k\pi}{4m})$ can be simplified (for $m=45$). I propose to formalize
this question as follows.

Let $U_n$ denote the set of all complex $n$-th roots of unity, and 
$U=\bigcup_{n\geq 0}U_n$.
Also, put

$$
\begin{array}{c}
L_n=\lbrace u_1+u_2+u_3+ \ldots +u_n | u_1,u_2, \ldots ,u_n \in U \rbrace, \\
L=\bigcup_{n\geq 0}L_n
\end{array}
$$

The  **additive complexity**  $c_{add}(l)$ of a number $l \in L$ is the smallest
$n$ such that $l\in L_n$. Define

$$
\begin{array}{c}
M_n=\lbrace x | x=l_1^{e_1}l_2^{e_2}l_3^{e_3} \ldots l_r^{e_r},
\ \text{with} \ e_i=\pm 1, l_i \in L (1\leq i \leq r), \sum_{k=1}^r 
c_{add}(l_k)\leq n  \rbrace,\\
M=\bigcup_{n\geq 0}M_n
\end{array}
$$
The  **additive-multiplicative complexity**  $c(m)$ of a number $m \in M$ is the smallest $n$ such that $m\in M_n$.

For example, the additive-multiplicative complexity of $t_n=\prod_{k=1}^m \tan(\frac{k\pi}{4m})$ is at most $3+4m$, since

$$
t_n=i^{(-m) \ {\sf mod}\ 4}\prod_{k=1}^{m}\frac{\zeta^k-\zeta^{-k}}{\zeta^k+\zeta^{-k}}
\ \ (\text{where} \ \zeta=e^{i\frac{k\pi}{4m}})
$$

Several questions can then be asked :

- Does the complexity of $t_n$ tend to infinity with $n$ ?
- What is the complexity of $t_{45}$ ? If this is too hard, can 
  some close lower/upper bounds be found ?

Comment: I'm curious about your notation **additive complexity** and **additive-multiplicative complexity**.  I've only ever seen additive complexity used in describing polynomials and computations.  If you're using it in the same fashion as other literature, could you please point me to it?  Or if you made it up, does it have a natural similarity to other uses?

Comment: @RyanTJohnson I am unaware of more standard notions that one could apply here.