# Hard Trigonometric Equation

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

its possible to solve a equation like

$$\prod^{45}_{k = 0} \left( 1 + \tan \frac{k \pi }{180} \right) = \left[ \log_{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}} \big| \sin(2x)\big| \right]^{\frac{9}{2}\sin(2x) + 20}$$

where I got this equation was wondering which of the intervals contained a solution of it?

1. $[0,631|0,747]$
2. $[0,258|0,395]$
3. $[0,412|0,627]$
4. $[0,799|0,814]$
5. $[0,041|0,107]$

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  Obviously it looks unpleasant at first glance, but are there any properties of this equation, or ones "like" it, that are particularly unpleasant that you know of?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75825/a-fast-way-for-computing-prod-limits-i-1451-tan-i-circ?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the link by lab you get that the product of the tan's  is $2^{23}$ if you set

$$\frac{9}{2}\sin (2x)+20=23$$ and

$$\log_{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}}\sin(2x)=2$$
you find in both cases that 
$$\sin(2x)=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: And given your answer, the answer to the OP's question is "yes!"

Comment: @abiessu I suppose, first there may be other answers, but you could try an increasing functions type argument to show there is at most one. Also I dont know what angle corresponds to $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, Do you have  a deterministic way to solve such a Transcendental equation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation). How do you establish the uniqueness?

Comment: If I understand your question, is there a general method in all cases to get exact solutions, the answer is no. For uniqueness you could try to understand if the function on the left is increasing, but its beyond me to even try.